# need 2d billboards to only draw when on the front of a node's geometry

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am rendering a sphere with some 2d planes (annotations) stuck on the sphere. I want the annotations to not render if they are on a point more than 90º from the vector pointing to the camera... if that makes sense.

Essentially I want the annotations to vanish when they are referencing a point on my sphere that the camera cannot see.

How would I accomplish this?

to clarify my example, I am making a 3d globe with annotations. I don't want the annotations on the back side of the sphere to render, but I also don't want annotations on the front side of the globe that are in the lower hemisphere to have their texture clipped. I was able to adjust the render order to fix the second issue, but then the first issue becomes a problem.

Update: thanks mnuages I was able to use this code to fix my issue

```
func renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {

    let position = scene.rootNode.convertPosition(annotation!.position, fromNode: globeNode)

    if position.z > 0 {
        annotation?.hidden = false
    } else {
        annotation?.hidden = true
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Should the nodes not render when they are outside the cameras field of view, or when they are behind another object, or when they themselves are rotated so that they appear infinitely thin to the camera?

Comment: I want the nodes to not render when obscured by my sphere, the trick is that I need them to also render in a way that they are not clipped by the sphere if they are in the lower hemisphere, and on the front side of the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. compute the coordinates of the center of the sphere in view space
2. compute the coordinates of the tracked point in view space
3. compute the vector from the center of the sphere to the tracked point in view space
4. if the `z` component of the previous vector is negative then the point is hidden (set the `hidden` property of the node to `YES`)

Comment: this raises a more basic question. where can I stick this code? it doesn't look like SCNScenes get update callbacks like SKScenes...unless I am missing something.

Comment: apparently because of the layout of my nodes, I could just use the annotations z position (converted to root node coordinates) but the method is sound... thanks!

Comment: they do. Have a look at the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocol.

Comment: yea, I figured that out. weird that its not just part of SCNScene subclass

Comment: it's more powerful. You can use the same delegate for different scenes, dynamically change the delegate, and avoid unnecessary subclasses. In general delegation is preferred to subclassing. When using SceneKit you should not have to subclass SCNScene.